# ODK Blank Form Error /Downloading Error "collect cannot reach the server?"

Tags: odk, odk-xform

i have installed the ODK Aggregation it work perfectly , but when i try to get Blank Form in ODK Collect it cannot download. it show the form it mean the server URL , User Name and Password are correct when i push the button to download it show the following error. "Collect Cannot reach the server http://MY_DOMAIN.com. Did you enter the URL correctly? if you keep having this problem, report to the person who asked you to collect the Data." if my url or password does not match then why ODK collect show my form with same name ID. Any one please

Answer (score 0):

[ODK Aggregate](https://forum.getodk.org/t/aggregate-is-no-longer-being-updated/33742) has reached of end-of-life is no longer supported. Switch to [ODK Central](https://docs.getodk.org/central-intro/) to resolve this problem.